# Send JS object from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The scenario that I have is the following.

I have a main web-site with a list of employees retrieved as a JSON from a backing service. I am using Handlebars engine for templating and it looks like follows.

**JSON**

```
[{"FirstName":"Tom","LastName":"Stephens","BirthPlace":"London","Gender":"M","OIB":"12345678901","CurrentPlace":"Berkeley","Department":"21510"},
{"FirstName":"Abigail","LastName":"Ybarra","BirthPlace":"Miami","Gender":"F","OIB":"12345678902","CurrentPlace":"Los Angeles","Department":"21540"},
{"FirstName":"Kim","LastName":"Kardashian","BirthPlace":"New York","Gender":"F","OIB":"12345678903","CurrentPlace":"Boston","Department":"UNKNOWN"},
{"FirstName":"David","LastName":"Beckham","BirthPlace":"London","Gender":"M","OIB":"12345678904","CurrentPlace":"Manchester","Department":"UNKNOWN"},
{"FirstName":"Zlatan","LastName":"Ibrahimovic","BirthPlace":"Stockholm","Gender":"M","OIB":"12345678905","CurrentPlace":"Zenica","Department":"21540"}]
```

**index.html**

```
<script id="employees-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
    {{#each employees}}
        <li>{{FirstName}}</li> <!-- use URL to a details website instead of FirstName -->
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

The list of employees is being fetched on a button click, which is defined as follows.

**main.js**

```
// on-click listener
    $("#btn-show").click(function(e) {
        // AJAX call on button clicked
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/",
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            // render data to html template
            var html = template({employees : data});
            $("#render-here").html(html);
        });
    });
```

This works like so: when a button is clicked, a list of employee names is rendered.

Now, what I want to achieve is that each of those names is actually a URL that leads to a page with all details about the specific employee.

For example, if a user clicks on URL "Tom" in a list, a new HTML page should open with all the details about Tom including *FirstName, LastName, BirthPlace, CurrentPlace etc*. This simple page can be called `employee.html`.

**employee.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>
            Firstname: {{FirstName}}
        </p>

        <p>
            LastName: {{LastName}}
        </p>

        <p>
            CurrentPlace: {{CurrentPlace}}
        </p>

        <p>
            BirthPlace: {{BirthPlace}}
        </p>

        <p>
            Gender: {{Gender}}
        </p>

        <p>
            Department: {{Department}}
        </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

The question is now how can I send all the details for a specific employee from my `main.html` page to a specific `employee.html` page (when the URL for a specific employee is clicked on)?

I understand I could pass all the parameters via the URL, but that seems really ugly forcing a user to see this unnecessary detailed URL.

Is there some better option?

Comment: You could stringify the data and [add it to localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Note: there are size limitations.

Comment: I believe you are using angularjs. Why not  make use of services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save it to `localStorage` and on the detail page retrieve the employee info from the local storage

You have to stringify the Json so it can be set to local storage (local storage only saves strings), and then set it to a variable in the local storage like this

```
localStorage["employees"] = JSON.stringify(json);
```

And to retrieve it use `Parse` to pars Json to and JS Object fron string like this

```
var employees = JSON.parse(localStorage["employees"]);
```

For more information on localStorage take a look at [localStorage - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: @DavidGenger With this approach, how will I know which URL triggered the new HTML page? I need to know exactly on which employee the user clicked, so that the details from exactly that user are shown. If someone clicked on "Tom" on index.html, somehow employee.html has to be aware of that the "Tom" was clicked on. How to do that?

Comment: @wesleyy You should pass in the id from the employee in the URL as a parameter, and in the JavaScript select the the employee matching that ID, or you can pass in the ID also in a new local storage key, and replace the value each time the user clicks on the list. I think the first approach is more desirable, so you can link directly to a user from URL

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`localStorage.setItem("employerList", JSON.stringify(employerData))` in the main page and the in the deail page use `var data = JSONparse(localStorage.getItem("employerList"))` and get you json in the data variable.